# sample size for difference-in-difference study

Tags: statistical-power, difference-in-difference, gpower

I want to do a difference-in-difference study of a prevalence estimate (binary data), but am struggling to find guidance on an appropriate power analysis/sample size calculation procedure.

The goal is to calculate the sample size necessary for an 7 percentage-point reduction in the adverse outcome in an intervention arm (so a decrease from 40% to 33% in intervention group if no change in controls), with 80% power at a 5% significance level. We're planning the same sample size for the intervention and control groups, and there will only be two data collection rounds (baseline/endline). We're not surveying the same individuals at baseline and endline.

Is there a calculation or a G*Power test for the basic sample size we could use (assuming simple random sampling) or would we need to run a simulation?

Comment: PASS 15 software can do that. G*Power is possible if you are willing to shift to extra sum of squares I believe. But simulation is straightforward as well. The three more things you will need to decide is group ratio (1:1 usually) and correlation between time points for you measured units, and SD.

Comment: I'm looking at binary outcome data though - so would this still be appropriate? I have a 1:1 group ratio as I said, and we're doing a cross-sectional survey so we're not going to be measuring the same individuals at baseline/endline. I've edited the question accordingly.